# securely automating a script which requires a key to do its task

Tags: scripting, security, password

I have a script that downloads bank transactions to store in a database. To get these transactions requires a password for each account. The database is encrypted and requires a key to access it. All these keys and passwords are themselves encrypted and require a master key to retreive. The script prompts for the master key, uses this to retrieve all the necessary passwords and keys, and then does its work.

Right now this script is being called manually. Automating it to run periodically is easy, except for the part of securing the master key. Simply storing it in a file in plaintext does not seem very secure, as anybody who manages to get read access to the file now has wide open access to a lot of sensitive information. Storing it in a way that the script has it (for example obfuscating it in a binary called by the script) won't work either, because then anyone who can execute the script has an attack vector there.

I have read [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87961/how-to-log-into-database-via-script-securely), the answer there appears to be "store it in a file" with added comments suggesting not in plain text. But even if the password is not plain text, it still seems like we have to communicate to the script how to read the file somehow, such as a decryption key or something, and we are back at square one.

Comment: What kind of key? If it's `gpg` you could use something like `gpg-agent`.

Comment: It's an AES-256 key.

Comment: What do you want to happen? Any method of automation will be exploitable. The root user can do anything.

Comment: Well, minimizing the risk would be a good start.

Comment: Don't you need a password to authenticate to the database anyway? So this is not exactly a new problem.

Comment: I assume you mean from the front end, but no, the backend is asynchronous, and the front end does not need to know the same key. However this does give me an idea, perhaps a separate persistant process could get the master key and keep it in memory, then it would only need to  be entered if the process went away e.g. after the infrequent reboot.

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232259/how-to-not-store-hdd-encryption-key-on-machine-but-still-mount-on-boot

Answer (score 2):

Put your keys in the environment as environment variables.

The way sites like Amazon aws and heroku recommend that you store sensitive information like keys and passwords are in environment variables.

Put the password in a text file that is readable only by you

Assuming this is a Mac or linux system:

```
touch foo.sh
```

Place the export in the file

```
nano foo.sh

export SOMESECRET=42
```

Then change the permissions

```
chmod 700 foo.sh
```

Then source the file

```
source foo.sh
```

The secret will only be available in that shell and subshells

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I wound up solving the problem.

First, I created a separate key server that starts up at the same time as the main server.  Its sole purpose is to hand out keys to authorized processes.  It does this by running an md5sum on the calling binary, then seeing which keys that binary is allowed to access.  The calling binary (in this case, the script, which has been compiled to an executable) requests the keys from this server and then proceeds as normal.

The key server runs all the time and maintains a keychain password in its own memory.  On startup, it does not have the keychain password, and thus cannot respond to requests for keys.  So before it can do this, it requires that the keychain password gets set.  This can be done via a web interface or the command line and requires user interaction.  This secures the system by requiring that somebody physically enter the correct password.  This generally only needs to be done once per reboot, since the key server never terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Store it in the database. If you are storing unencrypted bank transactions in the database, and someone has access to the database, then they can see the bank transactions anyway, so they don't need the master key.

Unless of course the master key does other stuff besides just accessing the data... but that would be bad security practice anyway.

Comment: The database is not un-encrypted.

Comment: I'm a little confused. How many databases are there here? 1? 2? Are you retrieving from, and storing into, the same database?

Comment: Two databases, both encrypted. One stores the key to the other, as well as passwords. The other stores transaction re cords.

Comment: Where does the output of your script go? Your question says "to store in a database". Which one?

Comment: The second one.